# Swift 4.2: Unable to add custom behaviour to a custom UITableViewCell using Protocol oriented delegate concepts

Tags: ios, swift4.2

I've a custom UITableViewCell, in that I've two UILabels & one UIButton. I'm able to load data...and display it as per requirement.

- **Problem Statement-1:** Now problem exist in my UIButton, which is in my `UICustomTableViewCell`. Due to this I'm unable to handle click event on that UIButton.
- **Problem Statement-2:** On button Click I have to identify the index of that Button click and pass data to next ViewController using `segue`.

---

Now have a look on...what did I've tried for this...

Yes, first-of-all I have thought that Binding IBOutlet action in my CustomCell will resolve my problem...but actually it doesn't solved my problem.

After that I've accessed button using `.tag` and initialised index path.row to it.

But it won't helped me.

So now I'm using **Protocol oriented concept** using **delegate** to handle click event on my UIButton which is available in CustomCell.

---

**What did I tried:**

**SwiftyTableViewCellDelegate:**

```
protocol SwiftyTableViewCellDelegate : class {
    func btnAuditTrailDidTapButton(_ sender: LeadCustomTableViewCell)
}
```

- **CustomTableViewCell with delegate:**

  ```
  class LeadCustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

      @IBOutlet weak var lblMeetingPersonName: UILabel!
      @IBOutlet weak var lblPolicyNo: UILabel!
      @IBOutlet weak var btnLeadAuditTrail: UIButton!


      weak var delegate: SwiftyTableViewCellDelegate?

      override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
          super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
      }

      @IBAction func btnAuditTrailTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
          delegate?.btnAuditTrailDidTapButton(self)
      }
  }
  ```

---

- **ViewController implementing delegate:**

  ```
  class LeadViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, SwiftyTableViewCellDelegate {

      //IBOutlet Connections - for UITableView
      @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

      override func viewDidLoad() {
          super.viewDidLoad()

          //setting dataSource & delegates of UITableView with this ViewController
          self.tableView.dataSource = self
          self.tableView.delegate = self

          //Reloading tableview with updated data
          self.tableView.reloadData()

          //Removing extra empty cells from UITableView
          self.tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
      }

      func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

          let cell:LeadCustomTableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! LeadCustomTableViewCell

          //Assigning respective array to its associated label
          cell.lblMeetingPersonName.text = (meetingPersonNameArray[indexPath.section] )
          cell.lblPolicyNo.text = (String(policyNoArray[indexPath.section]))

          cell.btnLeadAuditTrail.tag = indexPath.section
          cell.delegate = self

          return cell
      }

      //This is delegate function to handle buttonClick event

      func btnAuditTrailDidTapButton(_ sender: LeadCustomTableViewCell) {
          guard let tappedIndexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: sender) else { return }
          print("AuditTrailButtonClick", sender, tappedIndexPath)
      }
  ```

  Don't know why this is not working.

Comment: Does the print statement in the delegate method print anything?

Comment: Set a breakpoint in `btnAuditTrailTapped` - Is that function being called?  If not, you may not have connected the `touchUpInside` event to the function.

Comment: @hardikparmar no it does not print any thing.

Comment: Set a breakpoint or put a print statement before `guard let` statement. and see if it comes there or not.

Comment: Okay Sure, I'll try it.

Comment: No, it doesn't comes or not even that delegate function is called...

Comment: Now try what @Paulw11 has suggested and see if the `btnAuditTrailTapped` is being called or not.

Comment: Yeah thanks @Paulw11  for helping me. yes now it works on click event. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Thanks @hardikparmar

Answer (score 0):

Link the touch up inside event in cellForRow by adding the following code:

```
cell.btnLeadAuditTrail.addTarget(self, action:#selector(btnAuditTrailDidTapButton(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
```